# The collision settings for the point cloud are not displayed. How can I get the collision settings to appear?

Tags: point-clouds, unreal-engine5

The collision settings for the point cloud are not displayed. How can I get the collision settings to appear?
I'm using unreal engine5.1 and ubuntu22.04.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/lidar-point-cloud-plugin-quick-start-guide-in-unreal-engine/

[image]

I would like to set up collision using the above site as a reference, but it doesn't appear.

[image]